# Paypal Refund Option Programmatically

Tags: php, paypal

I have integrated paypal payment in my project .

I would like to include automatic refund option.

```
require_once('includes/paypal.class.php');
require_once('includes/paypal.adaptive.class.php');

include('includes/config.php');

// Create PayPal object.
$PayPalConfig = array(
    'Sandbox' => $sandbox,
    'DeveloperAccountEmail' =>   $developer_account_email,
    'ApplicationID' => $application_id,
    'DeviceID' => $device_id,
    'IPAddress' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
    'APIUsername' => $api_username,
    'APIPassword' => $api_password,
    'APISignature' => $api_signature,
    'APISubject' => $api_subject
 );

$PayPal = new PayPal_Adaptive($PayPalConfig);

// Prepare request arrays
$RefundFields = array(
    'CurrencyCode' => USD',                                             

    // Required.  Must specify code used for original payment.  You do not need to specify  if you use a payKey to refund a completed transaction.

    'PayKey' => '',                                             
    // Required.  The key used to create the payment that you want to refund.

    'TransactionID' => '7C0359353Y165821P', 

    // Required.  The    PayPal transaction ID associated with the payment that you want to refund.

    'TrackingID' => ''                                          

    // Required.  The tracking ID associated with the payment that you want to refund.
                  );

    $Receivers = array();
    $Receiver = array(
            'Email' => 'jilu@newagesmb.com',            
            // A receiver's email address. 
            'Amount' => '100.00',                                   

    // Amount to be debited to the receiver's account.
    'Primary' => '',
    // Set to true to indicate a chained payment.  Only one receiver can be a primary receiver.  Omit this field, or set to false for simple and parallel payments.

    'InvoiceID' => '',


    'PaymentType' => 'GOODS'        

    // The transaction subtype for the payment.  Allowable values are: GOODS, SERVICE
);

  array_push($Receivers, $Receiver);

  $PayPalRequestData = array(
                 'RefundFields' => $RefundFields, 
                 'Receivers' => $Receivers
                 );

//print_r($PayPalRequestData);exit;


$PayPalResult = $PayPal->Refund($PayPalRequestData);


echo '<pre />';
print_r($PayPalResult);
```

My Output is:

> 2014-04-28T02:54:20.805-07:00Failure55b35d9b576e810680030560022PLATFORMApplicationErrorApplicationThe X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID header contains an invalid valueX-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID

Comment: Is $sandbox evaluating to true?  Sounds like it's evaluating to false, but then you don't have a live value set for the App ID in the config file.  One way or another your App ID value getting passed into the header is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Did your application fully approved via PayPal?

You can check it from below link:

https://www.paypal-apps.com/user/my-account/applications

You can use application ID if it has been fully approved via PayPal. You can try this after confirmation from above URL.